# Equivalence Partition

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, manual-testing

If the temperature falls below 18 degrees, the heating is switched on.when the temperature reaches 21 degrees, the heating is switched off.what are the boundries solution for this problem?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Here is good explanation: https://www.guru99.com/equivalence-partitioning-boundary-value-analysis.html     and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCA8xOg_-S4

Answer (score 1):

Equivalence partitioning is a testing technique. The idea is to divide the input data into equivalent ("similar") classes and have a test case covering each partition at least one time. This technique is used to reduce the amount of test cases. 
In this given example, there are 2 main points where the state changes. So the line segments in between will represent the equivalent classes.

[image]

Class 1: less than 18 (the heating should be on)

Class 2: from 18 to 21

Class 3: greater than 21 (the heating should be off)

So the minimum set of input test values to cover all valid equivalence partitions would be one value from each of those classes. Let's say: 16, 20, 25

Comment: Above mentioned are standard ECP having three values from each above mentioned class. But if you want to test more then you can divide class 18 to 21 to more subclasses and can include a value from each of them. Also include `Boundary value Analysis` here by testing with values 18 and 21 itself.

Comment: The "test more" contradicts the idea of the technique, as it is used to reduce the number of tests. As well, what other equivalence classes could you add here? I agree with your point about the Boundary Value Analysis, but the question specifically asked about "valid equivalence partitions".

Answer (score 0):

Any one from min limit-18-20-21-Anyone from Max limit...

Answer (score 0):

The minimum is 3 values:2 outside the boundaries a<18, b>21 and one inside the range
http://istqbexamcertification.com/what-is-equivalence-partitioning-in-software-testing/

Answer (score -1):

If the temperature falls below 18 degrees, the heating is switched on.when the temperature reaches 21 degrees, the heating is switched off.what is the minimum set of test input values to cover all valid equivalence partitions?

**Ans:-**
Your temperature is 12,15,17 is heating.
your Temperature is 21,23,26 is no heating.
answer is 16,21,24.